# Can I consume in-app items on Android anytime I want?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I am trying to understand if Google Play allows "Delayed Consumable Items". Something I made up:

- Allow user to purchase a Golden-Key (for example).
- This Golden-Key will be repurchasable when it loses its shape.
- It should be valid on all the devices that is being used with the same Google Play account.
- It must not require a brand new membership system that works on my own server.
- It must not require me to query for the primary account on the device.

**Technically:**

Normally, I can always keep track of a non-consumable purchase as Google keeps it forever and as soon as user restores the purchases, all of them will be available for me on any device user have.

Things get tricky if I also want to add consumable items which I do not want to consume right away as consuming it will prevent me from tracking that purchase on other devices of the same user or if the user reinstalls the app. I can do it by first registering an account on my server and saving the consumed item on that account, but I do not want to show the user a signup or login system. I can also do it by retrieving the primary user account on the device and save it serverside, but I do not want to frighten user by requesting permission to those APIs.

So, I noticed that "I" am the person who manages the in-app items on the documentation, but I am not sure if I can assume the following:
- Let user buy an in-app item, but do not consume it until the user wants to purchase another one which may happen even after 3 years. (I will keep the order id on my server and prevent the user from accessing certain things if I mark that order id as used serverside. So, the user will intentionally hit "replace" button in the app and that button will consume the current in-app and start a new transaction.)

To cut it short, maybe I could summarise it in 1 sentence:
Can I consume an in-app item even after (for ex) 3 years, like a manual non-autorenawable subscription system where the duration is variable?

Comment: I think it's better you implement it in your server-side.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can explore Google Play Game API for your " I do not want to show the user a signup or login system" concern.https://developers.google.com/games/services/